# Unexpected delay in rospy subscriber

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do some image processing in a python subscriber callback, and I'm seeing some unexpected latency in the system.  It seems that even though I subscribe to a topic with `queue_size=1`, I still receive old messages.  Also, when I remove the `sleep(1.0)` call from my listener callback, I get `Delay: 0.019`, which is the expected result.

See code snippets below:

**talker.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('sensor_msgs')
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

rospy.init_node('talker')
pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', Image)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    msg = Image()
    msg.data = [0]*(640*480)
    msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    pub.publish(msg)
    rospy.sleep(0.05)
```

**listener.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('sensor_msgs')
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

def imageCb(msg):
    print "Delay:%6.3f" % (rospy.Time.now() - msg.header.stamp).to_sec()
    rospy.sleep(1.0)

rospy.init_node('listener')
sub = rospy.Subscriber('chatter', Image, imageCb, queue_size=1)
rospy.spin()
```

When I run both nodes, listener.py outputs the following:

```
Delay: 0.023
Delay: 0.950
Delay: 1.879
Delay: 1.950
Delay: 2.876
Delay: 3.805
Delay: 4.733
Delay: 5.657
Delay: 5.954
Delay: 5.954
Delay: 6.882
Delay: 6.916
Delay: 6.917
Delay: 6.918
Delay: 6.916
Delay: 6.917
```

Is this a bug in rospy?  Or, maybe there's some other Subscriber option that I should be using?

This is on Lucid/Fuerte system.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50112/unexpected-delay-in-rospy-subscriber/) by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 760 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-12-10**:
I'd look at the queing behavior on the publisher.

**Comment by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on 2012-12-10**:
I know roscpp publishers have a configurable queue_size.  Do python publishers have a similar option?  Also, I've seen the above issue also occur with a roscpp publisher with a queue_size=1.  This suggests that the rospy subscriber is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been able to remove the unexpected delay by adding a buff_size option to my subscriber:

```
sub = rospy.Subscriber('chatter', Image, imageCb, queue_size=1, buff_size=2**24)
```

I'm not totally sure what the implications are of adding a `buff_size` option nor am I sure why  solves the issue.  Better solutions/explanations are always welcome!

---

Originally posted by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) with karma: 760 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [basheersubei](https://answers.ros.org/users/7676/basheersubei/) on 2014-12-13**:
Oh my God this worked! I spent days trying to figure this out (at first I thought rospy had a bug with queue_size).

I think what's happening is that the default buff_size is too small for images, and so rospy just decides to use default infinite queue_size (and setting it to 1 won't help).

**Comment by [basheersubei](https://answers.ros.org/users/7676/basheersubei/) on 2014-12-13**:
Can someone check this? Is this a bug in rospy?

**Comment by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on 2017-05-30**:
See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/220502/image-subscriber-lag-despite-queue-1/?answer=220505#post-id-220505) for a great explanation for this behavior. :)